# XMLHttpRequest is sending "null" content type

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have following javascript code which is sending a `null` in content type

```
<script>
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var clientToken;
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
            clientToken = xhttp.responseText.content;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/client/123/token", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send();

    braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
        container: "payment-form"
    });
</script>
```

I am accessing this file outside of any server i.e., in browser I am putting

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. Why would you set a Content-Type request header on a GET request with no content to describe the type of?

Comment: The server side only accepts `application/json` content type and produces the same. When this wasn't set, the server was throwing `415` error i.e., `Unsupported media type`

Comment: Then the server is either hideously broken, or is assuming that nobody will even make a GET request to it.

Comment: Are you sure that it is making a request with `null` as the Content-Type header value and that it isn't making an OPTIONS request with no Content-Type header at all?

Comment: Thats what i just figured it out that it is sending `OPTIONS` method.